# How to optimize this query (PDO+MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to optimize this query that is related to a table of about 500.000 rows.

It contains three subqueries involving small tables (200>rows<1000).

Now, looking at phpmyadmin, the execution time is about 0.9 seconds, while printing some time variables using PHP it increases to about 2.2.

I tried to use indexes but using subqueries seems to break the index utilization (looking at the result of EXPLAIN)

```
SELECT `year`, `month`,`origin`, `destination`, `quantity`, LEFT(`hs_code` , 6) as code 
FROM table_x as tab WHERE (`origin` = (SELECT `code` FROM `table_y` as tab2 
WHERE tab2.`region_id`=1 AND tab2.`code`= tab.`origin`) AND `destination` = (SELECT `code` FROM `table_y` as tab2 WHERE tab2.`region_id`=1 AND tab2.`code`= tab.`destination`)) AND `hs_code` = (SELECT `code` FROM table_z WHERE `code`=tab.hs_code AND ((`type`='2' AND `sub_type`='1' ) OR (`type`='2' AND `sub_type`='2' ) OR (`type`='2' AND `sub_type`='3' ) OR (`type`='2' AND `sub_type`='4' ) OR (`type`='2' AND `sub_type`='5' ) OR (`type`='2' AND `sub_type`='6' )) LIMIT 1) AND export=1 AND `year`>=2016 AND (`year`<2019 OR (`year`=2019 AND `month`<=3)) ORDER BY `year` ASC, `month` ASC,`origin` ASC,`destination` ASC
```

This is the EXPLAIN outout

> 1PRIMARY tab ref export,table_x_index_origine,table_x_ind...
>   export 1 const 188731 Using index condition; Using where; Using
>   filesort
>
> 4 DEPENDENT SUBQUERY table_z ref code,tipologia code 767
>   tab.hs_code 6 Using where
>
> 3 DEPENDENT SUBQUERY tab2 eq_ref PRIMARY,table_y_index PRIMARY 6
>   tab.destination 1 Using where
>
> 2 DEPENDENT SUBQUERY tab2 eq_ref PRIMARY,table_y_index PRIMARY 6
>   tab.origin 1 Using where

and this is the table structure:

> id - INT | hs_code - VARCHAR | export - INT | origin - CHAR | destination -
>   CHAR | quantity - INT | value - INT | year - INT | month - INT

For me 0.9S of execution time would be good but I cannot achieve that result in PHP (using PDO) in any way i tried...

Comment: You may want to provide a sample table or something. It may be hard to help without knowing what your tables look like.

Comment: i would suggest rewritting the co-related subquery to a join instead, as a join tends to optimize much better in MySQL when indexes are involved.. But for more solid answers you should be proving table structures `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` for every table involved in the question.. And also providing the `EXPLAIN` output would help..

Comment: Thank you, I just added some more information

Comment: still incomplete when looking in the query you use more then one table and you should really execute for example `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_y` as we need to know indexes.. Also you should use the code formatting...

Comment: At the end, maximize the GROUP BY (so reducing the final rows number) was a good solution, now the running time is much lower